# Phone can't connect to PC to execute PHP file

Tags: android, json, gson

I created a database in my PC, and now I want to retrieve all table data and display them on my phone usin Google gson library by executing a php file in the server. The problem is the phone can't connect to the PC to execute that php file:

```
Error 403 for URL http://192.168.1.2/android_connect/get_all_products.php
```

I'm sure that the code is working cause i tested with that [online link](http://api.androidsmith.com/capitals.php) and data are retrieved in the phone.
The url is like that in JAVA code:

```
String url = "http://192.168.1.2/android_connect/get_all_products.php";
```

Is that correct? Is there something to do to let the phone connect to the PC?
Thank you for helping.

Comment: Your PC is on the same network as your phone, no?

Comment: @hd1: Of course, in the same network.

Comment: What program/service are you using to parse the PHP and for your database? xampp?

Comment: @jc6212: I really did not understand your question. I'm using gson Google library to parse data results from a php file.

Comment: Can you access the page from the Android emulator?

Comment: @hd1: I'll try with emulator okay ;)

Comment: @hd1: That's not working too, same 403 error.

Comment: What's your machine's IP address?

Comment: @hd1: You think that you can access my php file? Impossible.

Comment: No, but I'm wondering if YOU can access your PHP file remotely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To allow remote access to apache on Windows change the file: `c:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.2.22\conf\httpd.conf`

You need to allow remote access to directory C:\wamp\www like this:(add that lines)

```
<Directory "C:/wamp/www/">
    Order Deny,Allow
        Allow from all
</Directory>
```

And RESTART YOUR SERVER.

Answer (score 2):

You need to tune your PC's configuration to allow remote requests. Please [see what error 403](http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E403.html) is. It'd also help to check what's in your HTTPD logs concerning this request.

Comment: I'm in Windows, so i have to make some manipulation to let "outside" requests ?

Comment: What httpd you are using? Any type of XAMPP or so? Check access.log/error.log and see if it tells anything more (sometimes it does). Check your httpd config for any Deny directives...

Comment: I'm using wamp server with phpmyadmin. I think that wamp does not log requests. no ? (Thank you for your help)

Comment: wamp uses Apache. Apache logs, yet I am not familiar in details with wamp. Just look for `logs/` folder withing wamp installation. Apache should create `access.log` and `error.log` files. These are plain text file, so open in any sane text editor and check **last** entries

Comment: Post your apache2.conf somewhere. pastebin.com?

Comment: Problem solved ;). I was searching for a solution and found it. Please see my own answer (in 1 minute).

Comment: Thank you for your precious help. THANK YOU :).

Comment: That's why I wanted to see your apache2.conf for...  And my reputation points reward ;/.

Comment: Sorry dude :/ If there is something that i can do, you ask ;D

Comment: OMG, adding that lines blocked WAMP from puting online! I though that worked! I have to search more so!

Comment: XAMPP is more powerful than WAMP ?

Comment: No. WAMP, XAMPP - these are same components like httpd (apache), PHP, mySQL, Postgress and some modules. Nothing more or less powerful. I personally prefer UniformServer (and I prefer older Mona serie over current, imho bloated one).

Comment: That's completely not logical to see wamp bloqued when adding that bloc. Can you test it please in your server and see if it's starts or not?

Comment: I'd change `Order` to `Order Deny,Allow` (which is default and means `allow anyone, unless explictely denied`. ) or remove both `Order` and `Allow` and restart your server (ensure you stop it and start again, not just restart).

Comment: I did what you told me to do and always the same problem... :/

Comment: I removed that lines `ExecCGI MultiViews
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride all` and now wamp is working. However, i have that problem now `W/System.err(25309): org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://192.168.1.2 refused
`